# Installing caret package in R

Tags: r, r-caret

When I tried to load package of "caret" for my logistic regression model in R, the error message says "package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’.....". Is it an issue of my R version? I have 1.1.456 version.

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
crossValSettings <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10,savePredictions = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you please include the exactl output and error message?

Comment: > library(caret)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘generics’ 0.0.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.1.0 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.6.3

Comment: Try updating the old package. Restart R and run `install.packages("generics")`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I did what you suggested and the function "trainControl" worked! Thanks!